# Email Service Provider where a Transactional Email can be sent using a Template created using its Web interface

Tags: email, templates, sendgrid, transactional

A company I am developing for needs an email service provider where its own non-technical design staff can create an email template using the provider's design web interface. Transactional emails are to be sent to a single recipient specifying the stored template plus insert values.

This is currently being done using MadMimi, and the company wants to also use a second provider for backup.

I have examined the SendGrid documentation, but apparently its web design tool produces templates which can be used only for email sent to lists, not to individual recipients.

(Note: I am coding in Ruby on Rails, but that is irrelevant to this issue.)

Can anyone suggest alternative providers which fit the requirements? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, SendGrid's Transactional Template engine allows non-technical people to edit emails meant to be sent to individual people. More can be found on [SendGrid's product page](http://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-template-engine) and [documentation pages](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Template_Engine_API/index.html).

Comment: Tip: if you're using SendGrid's template engine, be sure to save your email templates to source control because their app reformats HTML when you edit/save and it sometimes removes elements and other html. (really frustrating) Other than that, it's a great solution.